# Alert is not getting displayed in onbeforeunload event in any browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, onbeforeunload

Below is the code which works.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    someAjaxCall();
}
```

Below is the code which does not work.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    someAjaxCall();
    alert("Success !!");
}
```

Can I not put alerts in onbeforeunload?

Answer (score 0):

you can get a dialog with return.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Success !!";
}
```

Comment: But I also want to do an ajax call. If i use return then ajaxCall is not called.

Comment: Also, I don't want any confirmation message. I just want to do an ajax call and inform user that data is saved.

Comment: ok for the ajax call sending a sync request should work I think,  $.ajax({ type: 'GET',    async: false,...  Also onbeforeunload works in Chrome and other browsers need $(window).on("unload",... but you would need to add code so that if one had executed the other shouldn't. i'm not sure about showing a non confirm dialog.

Comment: Ajax call is working properly. It doesn't work when the alert is given. And even the alert does not come up. Why so?